# mapbox-gl-native not compiling with XCode 12

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-errors, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I downloaded the master for mapbox-gl-native, installed needed dependencies, followed instructions, then tried to build with "cmake --build build" but I get a lot of errors.

**This is the first error:**

```
[  8%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/mbgl-core.dir/src/mbgl/layermanager/circle_layer_factory.cpp.o
In file included from /Users/imac/Work/GitHub/mapbox-gl-native/src/mbgl/layermanager/circle_layer_factory.cpp:1:
In file included from /Users/imac/Work/GitHub/mapbox-gl-native/include/mbgl/layermanager/circle_layer_factory.hpp:3:
In file included from /Users/imac/Work/GitHub/mapbox-gl-native/include/mbgl/layermanager/layer_factory.hpp:3:
In file included from /Users/imac/Work/GitHub/mapbox-gl-native/include/mbgl/style/layer.hpp:3:
In file included from /Users/imac/Work/GitHub/mapbox-gl-native/include/mbgl/style/conversion.hpp:3:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:504:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string_view:175:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__string:57:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/algorithm:642:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/utility:199:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__tuple:283:5: error: static_assert failed due to
      requirement '0UL < sizeof...(_Types)' "tuple_element index out of range"
    static_assert(_Ip < sizeof...(_Types), "tuple_element index out of range");
    ^             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__tuple:457:43: note: in instantiation of template class
      'std::__1::tuple_element<0, std::__1::__tuple_types<> >' requested here
    typedef _LIBCPP_NODEBUG_TYPE typename tuple_element<_Ip, __tuple_types<_Tp...> >::type type;
                                          ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/tuple:1007:10: note: in instantiation of template class
      'std::__1::tuple_element<0, std::__1::tuple<> >' requested here
typename tuple_element<_Ip, tuple<_Tp...> >::type&
         ^
/Users/imac/Work/GitHub/mapbox-gl-native/include/mbgl/util/indexed_tuple.hpp:38:16: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function template 'get'
      [with _Ip = 0, _Tp = <>]
        return std::get<TypeIndex<I, Is...>::value, Ts...>(*this);
               ^
/Users/imac/Work/GitHub/mapbox-gl-native/src/mbgl/layout/circle_layout.hpp:20:59: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'mbgl::IndexedTuple<mbgl::TypeList<mbgl::style::CircleSortKey>, mbgl::TypeList<mbgl::style::PropertyValue<float> > >::get<mbgl::style::CircleSortKey>'
      requested here
        const bool sortFeaturesByKey = !unevaluatedLayout.get<style::CircleSortKey>().isUndefined();
                                                          ^
```

**This is the result for: "gcc --version"**

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

**This is the result for: "cmake . -B build"**

```
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 12.0.0.12000032
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 12.0.0.12000032
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Configuring GL-Native with OpenGL renderer backend
-- Found OpenGL: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework   
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/local/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.29.2") 
-- Checking for one of the modules 'glfw3'
-- Not building node bindings, dependencies not found. Run 'npm update'.
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/imac/Work/GitHub/mapbox-gl-native/build
```

**NOTE:** I have an older version of mapbox environment (July 2019) that was perfectly compiling with XCode (compiling inside XCode) but as soon as I installed XCode 12 I started to have the same error.